# Get URL parameters from child window and load parent window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm searching a way to do this: How can I get the URL parameters from a child window, and then, use these parameters to load a specific URL but on the parent window ?

In fact, I have a link on a page. When I click on this link, a "popup" is load with some parameters : `http://www.site.com/page.php?id=5&ab=42`.
On this popup, there is a small form, and when I click on submit, I would like close this popup, and load a specific page on my parent window using the parameters from my popup:
`http://www.site.com/result.php?id=5&ab=42`.

I guess there is a way on Javascript, but I'm not really an expert in this language.

Please, let me know if you find a solution. 
Thank you all!

Lapinou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Open pop up
window.open('http://www.site.com/page.php?id=5&ab=42');



// On pop up page, redirect parent window
window.opener.parent.location.href = 'http://www.site.com/result.php?id=5&ab=42';
```

Comment: Really ? Only that! I try right now! :) Thank you @nigro.simone!